# WebDriver throws org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException while using Firefox browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm using below configurations :

> Gecko Driver Version: 0.17
>
> FireFox Version: 54.0.1
>
> Selenium Java  Version: 3.4.0

Tried below code to open the browser :

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", properties.getProperty("FireFoxDriverPath"));
driver = new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

But encountered with below Exception:

> FAILED: testRunner("Instance1", LOCAL, FIREFOX, 1, 1)
> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new
> remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true,
> firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@596982,
> browserName=firefox,
> moz:firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@596982,
> version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
> Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18
> 09:49:13 -0700'

Can anyone please clarify what is the issue ?

Comment: Try to update the chrome and let me your outcome.

Comment: You mentioned `Selenium Java Version: 3.4.0` where as your error stack trace says `Build info: version: '3.0.1'` Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB Though i have updated selenium version from 3.0.1 to 3.4.0 in maven dependency while running it is still showing as 3.0.1. Apart from updating version in maven do i need to follow any other steps? Please help!!

Comment: @Saad For chrome it is successfully running.

Comment: Do remember to do a `maven clean`, next `maven install` then only `maven test`. That would remove away all the rotten stuffs. Consider bumping up your `gecko` to v0.18.0 as v0.18.0 appears to be a bit more stable then its previous release. Thanks

Comment: Sorry my mistake.. Try to update firefox driver and let me know your outcome.

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks for the info. While running maven install i'am build failure message. Can you please clarify!!

Comment: After changing the `pom.xml` through eclipse either you didn't save the settings or you missed to `clean` & `install` that's why you are still seeing `version: '3.0.1'`. Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB Please help me to get solution for the below question link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493597/how-to-handle-windows-authenticated-popup-in-seleniumjava-using-mac-machine